# Is it possible to simplify this mesh? I have too many vertices

Tags: modeling, optimization

I'm struggling to work my model with this amount of edge-loops/handles. Can anyone suggest a less cumbersome approach?

[image: Vertices]

[image: Smooth]

[image: Direction I want]

Comment: I think there is no answer to exactly how you could reduce vertices: you could "simplify" but it always come to this: every face is a plane (triangle, quad or n-gon), and topology usually matters. So, to retain the overall exact shape, you can only somehow "aggregate" complanar adjacent faces (eg: using n-gons) but your topology will be worse. Depending on the model, using only quads gives usually the best topology, and many tools can help you (llop tools, etc).

Comment: I think it would be hard to represent the curvature of the object with less vertices.

Comment: This looks real good. Just use a lower subdivision level.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to keep the overall topology of the hood, you cannot. However if you do want less vertices, there are two ways to go about doing this. The first being to lower the subdivison surface modifier. Of course this only works if you used a sud surf modifier in the first place and haven't applied it. The second way is to delete loop cuts. To begin go into edit mode and select the loop(s) you wish to remove by pressing ALT + RightClick. Press SHIFT + ALT + RightClick to select more than one. [image: One loop selected] Once selected press x to open the remove tab, finally press G to remove the loop cut. [image: Loop cut sucsefully deleted]

Answer (score 1):

Ben, although I can imagine a situation in which the number of vertices in the hood of the car are "too many", without any other information, I don't know why you think you have too many--certainly not on the order of tens of vertices too many. I can't imagine how to get the shapes of your hood with fewer. The mesh is really rather simple as it stands, and there's not much I can think of to do to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify it follow the image, remove those 5 edges

[image: show.phpenter image description here]

Comment: please link the images directly into the answer and not on external site. Pasteall.org links expire within a few weeks and your answer will make no sense then. To include images in to your answers use this tool: http://i.stack.imgur.com/F9FMw.png

Comment: How do you do to that? i tried it didn't work

Comment: the icon looks like a picutre with landscape, as in this link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/F9FMw.png